gulp 5 src() make the images format unsupported
I have some images in my project that I want to compress them using gulp
But first I want to move them to the dist folder so I made this simple task
function test(){
    return src("src/images/*").pipe(dest("dist"))
}

this worked fine before in gulp@4.0.2.
But now using gulp@5.0.0 the images moved to the folder but they refuse to render in html! and I can't open them anymore look at the screenshot (I'm using Microsoft Photo)

Also, this is using the VS code

Looks like src() changed the imaged format and thus destroyed it!
Anyone could help with this?

This question is similar to: Copying images with Gulp are corrupted/damaged. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

it looks like the same problem. Thanks

you may try adding { encoding: false } :
function test(){
    return src("src/images/*", { encoding: false }).pipe(dest("dist"))
}

I was having issues copying and serving fonts when I upgraded to gulp 5:
Failed to decode downloaded font
OTS parsing error: incorrect file size in WOFF header
https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2797
Gulp options:
https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/src#options


This fix the issue thanks
